# No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/> - deploy pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to deploy my angular front end to an Azure app service. I have successfully set up a pipeline using YAML. However, when I try to deploy the pipeline I get this error ' No package found with the specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.'

I've added the following line into my YAMl file, but am still getting an error '- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1'

This is my YAML file:

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
 vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
 inputs:
   versionSpec: '18.x'
 displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   npm install
   ng build --configuration production
 displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error seems it is having path issues with the build artifacts. I have tried to repro the same and got results as expected.

Add Publish build artifact task with path to publish build folder in build pipeline as below.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'build'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The above task will publish files in build folder to the drop artifact.

Next, run the build verify the build artifacts in the output  whether it is generated or not.

[image]

[image]

The angular build artifacts generated as a normal files, not as a zip folder.

Now create release pipeline as below.
Navigate to **releases**, click **Add an artifact** and choose right project and build pipeline to pull artifacts while deploying.

[image]

Next add **azure app service deploy task** and modify the path at **Package or folder** as shown below.
[image]

Create release and verify the result.
[image]

Comment: thanks for your response! I've tried to updated myYAML file to include'- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'build'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'' but have gotten this error '##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/s/build'

Comment: @BethMcCoy pls try replacing 'build' with 'dist' and let me know whether it worked or not.